# How to setup a Moq Callback for an `in` parameter modifier?

Tags: c#, moq

How do you setup a Moq setup Callback for a method with an [`in` parameter modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/in-parameter-modifier)?

Say you have this:

```cs
public interface ITester
{
   bool IsGood(in int value);
}
```

This doesn't work:

```cs
var mock = new Mock<ITester>();
mock.Setup(m => m.IsGood(It.IsAny<int>()))
    .Callback<int>(v => { /* whatever */ });  // ==> runtime error

mock.Object.IsGood(42);
```

You get the following exception:

```
System.ArgumentException : Invalid callback. Setup on method with parameters (in int) cannot invoke callback with parameters (int).
```

What's the correct way (apart from removing the `in` modifier altogether ;) )?

Comment: Have you considered trying the same approach given in the docs for `ref` and `out`? https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#callbacks

Comment: Change the callback to use `.Callback((int v) => { /* whatever */ }); ` instead so that the code can infer which `Callback` extension you intended to use.

Comment: I had looked at the very page... and miss it. It does work with a delegate. Make it an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to define the `delegate` with the similar signature(match input arguments) and use it in the callback + use `It.Ref<int>.IsAny` in the setup:

```
public delegate void MyDelegate(in int value);
var d = new MyDelegate((in int a) => { Console.WriteLine($"Number {a}"); });

var mock = new Mock<ITester>();
mock.Setup(m => m.IsGood(It.Ref<int>.IsAny)).Callback(d);

mock.Object.IsGood(42); //Number 42
```